# Slow ASP.net start up

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have reinstalled Windows 10 from scratch and on day two, I make a simple change to my ASP.net website and it takes 39 seconds for it to load in the browser.

How do I find out what is making it so slow? Once loaded, it's quick.

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows Server OS, or another?...can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You profile the site and figure out where the slowdown is. Add logging etc.

Comment: @mason It's in the start up. Once it's loaded, the pages are quick.

Comment: So add logging in the startup and figure out what is slow to start up. At least see if it's your application code.

Comment: @mason ok I will!

Answer (score 0):

Oh my Lordy, I disabled Edit and Continue. Now it's fast.

I'm not sure I've ever even used Edit and Continue.